# How do I hide a /public/ directory in htacess

Tags: .htaccess

My website is website.com/public/login.php. That looks a bit ugly. How do you rewrite htaccess to say website.com/login.php?

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Your rule looks ok . What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Could it be the `RewriteBase /public/`? I didn't spot than when I wrote my answer, but now it's obvious that one cannot match `/login` when the `RewriteBase` is different from that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Solved. It hides /public/ 
   website.com/login.php instead of 
   website.com/public/login.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RewriteRule` that strips off the `/public/` path is currently an *external redirect*, because of the `R=`. Since you want the result of that rule to be hidden, it should rather be an *internal redirect* (also called URL *forwarding*), and that is written without the `R=302` option.

While you're at it, you could also hide the `.php` from the externally visible URLs since a simple `/login` looks much cleaner than `/login.php`.

Comment: how do I hide the .php?

Comment: The op is already using an internal rewrite rule to map `/login.php` to `/public/login.php` . The first rule that does an external redirection is there just to change `/public/login.php` to `/login.php` .